# How can I [simply] consume JSON Data in a Line of Business Web Application

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services, json

I usually use JSON with jQuery to just return a string with html. However, I want to start to use Javascript objects in my code.

What's the simplest way to get started using json objects on my page?

Here's a sample Ajax call ( after `$(document).ready( { ... })` of course:

```
 $('#btn').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var out = $('#result');
     $.ajax({ url: "CustomerServices.asmx/GetCustomersByInvoiceCount",
          success: function(msg) {
             // 
             // Iterate through the json results and spit them out to a page?
             // 
          },
                data: "{ 'invoiceCount' : 100 }"
     });
 });
```

My WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod(Description="Gets customers with more than n invoices")]
public List<Customer> GetCustomersByInvoiceCount(int? invoiceCount) {
    using (dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext()) {

        return db.Customers.Where(c => c.InvoiceCount >= invoiceCount);
    }
}
```

What gets returned:

```
{"d":[{"__type":"Customer","Account":"1116317","Name":"SOME COMPANY","Address":"UNit 1             , 392 JOHN ST.                            ","LastTransaction":"\/Date(1268294400000)\/","HighestBalance":13922.34},{"__type":"Customer","Account":"1116318","Name":"ANOTHER COMPANY","Address":"UNIT #345             , 392 JOHN ST.                            ","LastTransaction":"\/Date(1265097600000)\/","HighestBalance":549.42}]}
```

What I'd LIKE to know, is what are people generally doing with this returned json? Do you iterate through the properties and create an html table on the fly?

Is there way to "bind" JSON data using a javascript version of reflection ( something like the .Net GridView Control )

Do you throw this returned data into a Javascript Object and then do something with it?

An example of what I want to achieve is to have an plain ol' html page ( on a mobile device )with a list of a Salesperson's Customers. When one of those customers are clicked, the customer id gets sent to a webservice which retrieves the customer details that are relevant to a sales person.

I know the SO talent pool is quite deep so I figured you all here would be able to guide in the right direction and give me a few ideas on the best way to approach this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you have a look a the various client template solutions available. There are even talks of integration this with the next jQuery release [**here**](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-templates-proposal).

I prefer [**jTemplate**](http://jtemplates.tpython.com/) for its simplicity and small size. But there are others. If you want to see it in action check one of our clients sites [**here**](http://www.bet-mate.com).
We found that it scales very well even to a large amount of rows (>1000).

Comment: Thanks for the sample site! Looks like you're binding to a WCF Service as well. You prefer them to SOAP?

Comment: Actually the same WCF service is also exposing a SOAP/XML endpoint. But this is for background services only. The amount of traffic overhead was simply to large (factor 10) for the frontend. Since we are running 100k+ requests/h this was simply unbearable AND its much simpler to handle rest + json in jquery. We would definitely do it again this way.

Comment: Interesting. TO be honest, I've been thinking of switching to using WCF but I haven't put in the time to grok WCF.

Comment: I would definitely recommend having a look at it, being able to change the format by simply modifying the endpoint configuration is something that really pay off as soon as you get the hang of it.  

To be perfectly honest to get the REST interface working some additional attributes had to be added in the code, but this has become much more intuitive in .NET 4, also the configuration horrors of WCF were greatly reduced along with good tracing abilities.